# How rewrite (most) subdomains in nginx to a virtual path for an API/proxy

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, cname-record

I have a tenant setup where a unknown number of companies could create accounts, of the kind `company.app.com`.

The backend server them as `: 5000/company/....`, so how do a rewrite (not a redirect!) in nginx? This is what I have:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl        on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

    server_name ????.app.com; <-- How?
    
    charset    utf-8;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://0.0.0.0:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_connect_timeout       300;
        proxy_send_timeout          300;
        proxy_read_timeout          300;
        send_timeout                300;            
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

Now the issues is that I need to rule out a small list of subdomains (www, dash, mail) so how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can capture part of the `Host` header / TLS SNI field into a variable in `server_name` like this:

```
server_name ~^(?<company>.+)\.app\.com;
```

Later on, the variable can be used in `proxy_pass` destination:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.100.100:5000/$company/;
```

It is useful to know the matching rules, which are explained in [nginx server names documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Answer (score 0):

My comment would be to long for a comment, excuse me.

In Reference to the NGINX Documentation:

> A wildcard name may contain
> an asterisk only on the name’s start or end, and only on a dot border.
> The names “www.*.example.org” and “w*.example.org” are invalid.
> However, these names can be specified using regular expressions, for
> example, “~^www..+.example.org$” and “~^w.*.example.org$”. An
> asterisk can match several name parts. The name “*.example.org”
> matches not only [www.example.org](http://www.example.org) but [www.sub.example.org](http://www.sub.example.org) as well.
>
> When searching for a virtual server by name, if name matches more than one of the specified variants, e.g. both wildcard name and regular expression match, the first matching variant will be chosen, in the following order of precedence:
>
> - exact name
> - longest wildcard name starting with an asterisk, e.g. “*.example.org”
> - longest wildcard name ending with an asterisk, e.g. “mail.*”
> - first matching regular expression (in order of appearance in a configuration file)
>
> A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to
> match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name
> “*.example.org”.

Since NGINX supports wildcard it could be like:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
ssl        on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

server_name *.app.com;

charset    utf-8;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout          300;
    proxy_read_timeout          300;
    send_timeout                300;            
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
}
```

or even:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
ssl        on;
ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/key.pem;

server_name *corp.app.com;

charset    utf-8;

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout          300;
    proxy_read_timeout          300;
    send_timeout                300;            
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
}
```

Both should work.

Comment: I do this and the server do redirects as "*.app.com" instead of "name.app.com"

Comment: @mamcx show me the redirect part

Comment: I found was the presence of X-Forwarded-Host, I remove it and this work.